# Python - Read files and add the data to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

The issue here is that I want to read a lot of files from a folder and add the data into a 2D list.

Let's that I have the following two txt files in my folder

The first file is *fruits.txt* with the following content:

```
apple
orange
banana
```

The second file is *colors.txt* with the following content:

```
yellow
blue
```

Now I want to add the data from *fruits.txt* and *colors.txt* into a 2D list like below:

```
myList[fruits][apple]
myList[fruits][orange]
myList[fruits][banana]
myList[colors][yellow]
myList[colors][blue]
```

As you can see in the first dimension is the name of the file and in second dimension is a line from the file.

Not sure how can be implemented this and if its better to add the data in a dictionary

Comment: *2D list*? you mean dictionary

Comment: `myList` would need to be a dictionary then: lists can only be indexed with integers, not strings. It'll also have to be a dictionary of dictionaries - for the same reason

Comment: Or do you want a `dict` of `list`s, like `{'fruits': ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'], 'colors': ['yellow', 'blue']}`?

Comment: @chepner A dict of lists looks like is my solution.. I have tried to implement this but with no success..

Comment: @ForceBru Yep you are right!

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yep, I was not sure if it possible to be implemented with lists too!

Comment: But it can be implemented with lists: `[[['fruits', ['apple','orange','banana']], ['colors', ['yellow','blue']]]`. It depends on what you need this for.

Comment: What's the expectation output?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA after saving the results in my list or dictionary, I would like be able to retrieve all the data for further processing e.g. all lines from colors.txt

Comment: So chepner's example is what you want?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Yep, seems the best solution so far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is what you want?

```
with open("fruits.txt",'r') as f:
    fruits = f.read().split("\n")

with open("colors.txt","r") as f:
    colors = f.read().split("\n")

Result = {'fruits':fruits,'colors':colors}
# {'fruits': ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'], 'colors': ['yellow', 'blue']}
```

Or if you want to read all the file in current directory.
Your folder construction:

```
- Yourfolder
   - fruits.txt
   - colors.txt
.....
```

You can use `glob` module to read all the `*.txt` files:

```
import glob

Result = {}
for name in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(name,'r') as f:
        Result[name.split(".")[0]] = f.read().strip().split("\n")

print(Result)
```

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I need! In this line `Result[name.split(".")[0]] = f.read().split("\n")` because most of the time in the lines of txt files are dots, I lost the correct name. I have tried `Result[name.split(".txt")[0]] = f.read().split("\n")` but is not working!

Comment: I mean, most of the time in the file name of txt files are dots, so I lost the correct name in dictionary. I have tried Result[name.split(".txt")[0]] = f.read().split("\n") but is not working!

Comment: It was my mistake to say in my comment `inside the lines of files`. The dots are inside the filename e.g. `colors.us.txt`. In this case I want to keep `colors.us` and not `colors`. Or maybe the filename is `colors.us.1.txt`

Comment: Okay,I know that.

Comment: I have noticed that for each file is adding one empty value: `# {'fruits': ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', ''], 'colors': ['yellow', 'blue', '']}`
Split function cannot work by using one dot and more characters together?

Comment: @Csalt Not a big case,I edited my post.You can remove the last `\n` by `strip()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211359/discussion-between-csalt-and-jizhihaosama).